# Cypress Newbie : Unfound Elements

Tags: javascript, cypress

Just started using Cypress following fun with Protractor/Jasmine. Going OK on the whole and tests are running fine using the Cypress UI - both Chrome and Electron.

However, when I run headless Electron in VS Code or a VSTS Pipeline, I get unfound element errors. The elements are 'in your face' when running in a browser so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here's an example - (The previous spec loads the URL)

```
describe('OBM Smoketests', function() {
it('Select Hotel and Enter Search Dates', function() {


    cy.get('.jss189 > div > .jss69 > .jss230 > .jss72').click({force: true});

    cy.get('[value="OBMNG3"]').click();
    cy.wait(1000);


});
});
```

I've been using the Selector Playground and as can be seen, tried the 'force'. Here's thenerror:

```
1) OBM Smoketests Select Hotel and Enter Search Dates:
 CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.jss189 > div > .jss69 > .jss230 > .jss72', but never found it.
  at Object.cypressErr (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:62993:11)
  at Object.throwErr (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:62958:18)
  at Object.throwErrByPath (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:62985:17)
  at retry (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:56601:16)
  at http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:48711:18
  at tryCatcher (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:124200:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:122218:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:122275:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:122320:10)
  at Promise._settlePromises (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:122395:18)
  at Async._drainQueue (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:119124:16)
  at Async._drainQueues (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:119134:10)
  at Async.drainQueues (http://localhost:58691/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:119008:14)
  at <anonymous>
```

Anyone offer some advice please?
Thanks

**more info**

Although when running headless in Electron, the console output states that three specs have been found and seems to run them one after another, I have since tried

```
cypress run --headed
```

...now I see that after the first spec has run, the browser is closed down and re-started for the next spec...which assumes that the browser has remained open...as if you were doing the same thing in Selenium!

There must be a way of running specs concurrently without have to re-open the browser...or is it a case of long specs?

Comment: Have you tried finding a simpler element on the screen? Something not as deep in the dom hierachy. If you can do that then I'd try iterating down your selectors until it breaks. I've had weirdness before where I can see the element, but the browser/cypress is not happy about the css being applied to it. You may also want to check to see what version of things you're running when you run headless. AFAIK headless and the UI version use two different implementations.

Comment: Do any of your test work? Something odd is going on here. Can you see the title of the page with a test, etc? something simple.

Comment: @Maccurt - hi...yes the tests run fine in Chrome and Headed Electron. There are three specs of which this is the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you put wait(1000) after first cy.get?

Can you use selector playground for the first element? (.jss189 > div > .jss69 > .jss230 > .jss72) and try again?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set an unique test ID to the element which you want to get. Something like

`data_cy = element1`

and then use get function like this

`cy.get('[data_cy=element1]').click()`